# How do you check if a transformation is injective and/or surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a transformation F that takes a 2x2 matrix.

So I need to put the transformation matrix in reduced row echelon form, and then what?

Comment: A linear map between two finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension (i.e. square matrix) is either both injective and surjective, or neither.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the transformation in reduced row echelon form and it's the identity matrix then it's bijective (injective and surjective).  A matrix can be injective or surjective without being bijective only if it is not square.

Answer (score 1):

Find rank and hence nullity of $F$. If nullity is $0$ then its kernel is trivial and so it is one one and then its rank is 2 (as it is $2\times 2 $ matrix) and so its range space is the whole codomain and thus the map is onto.